# Object re-assign preventing http subscription

Tags: javascript, .net, angular

I am passing an object from a parent component to a child component.

Relevant parent html:

```
<app-child-component
   [parentObj]="parentObj"
   (childUpdated)="childUpdated($event)">
</app-child-component>
```

Child component:

```
@Input('parentObj') parentObj: ParentObjType;
parentObjToUpdate: ParentObjType;
```

I take a copy of the `parentObj` within the child component to prevent a circular reference issue I previously had:

Child component:

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.parentObjToUpdate = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.parentObj));
    }
```

When the child gets updated, an event is emitted containing the `parentObjToUpdate` which is listened to by the parent:

Child component:

```
@Output() childUpdated = new EventEmitter<ParentObjType>();
```

The `childUpdated` method is then called in the parent component:

```
originalObj: ParentObjectType;

childUpdated(updatedObj: ParentObjectType) {
  this.originalObj = updatedObj; // THIS IS THE LINE THAT IS CAUSING THE ISSUE (SEE BELOW)
  this.httpService.updateObj(this.originalObj).subscribe(() => {
     console.log("END POINT HIT");
 });
}
```

This is the httpService:

```
 public updateObj(originalUpdatedObject: ParentObjectType) {
            return this.http.post<any>(`http://localhost:12345/api/updateObj`, originalUpdatedObject);
        }
```

When I comment out the line above: `this.originalObject = updatedObj;`, the .NET end point is being hit and the above `console.log` gets triggered. When this line is not commented out, the end point is not being hit and the subscription does not get triggered. There are no errors in the console. I've checked the network tab on the Chrome developer tools and no request is being made to the API.

I'm really confused about why this is happening?

Please note - I cannot just pass in the `updatedObj` into the http service method as I need to update the original object in my scenario. Also, the names of the objects/components etc have been changed from the actual names.

Comment: Have you tried: `this.originalObj = {...updatedObj};`?

Comment: I did use the spread operator and the issue still persisted. There are nested objects/arrays within the `updatedObj`. So obviously the spread operator is only making a 'shallow' copy of the `updatedObj` and will not make a copy of the nested objects/arrays. Could this be causing the issue? Why would this be preventing the end point from being hit though?

Comment: @BailP Why you want this line `this.originalObj = updatedObj` ?

Comment: In the scenario I have, I need to update the original object. Why would this be causing the subscription to not be triggered though?

Comment: It is unclear to me from your sample why you need to pass your objects around in such a manner. In the simple case, mutating an object received in an `@Input()` will also mutate this object in the parent component, exactly in the same way as if you pass an object into a function and mutate it. Why would this cause a cyclical dependency?

Comment: In my scenario, the object which is passed down to the child is used to set initial values in a reactive form. Originally, I was just allowing the form to then update this object when the user interacts with the form. I believe this is where the circular reference was occurring (although I am not 100% sure). When trying to pass this object into the http call, this circular referencing was triggering an error when the http method was serializing the object

Comment: @MikkelChristensen. Are you eluding to the fact that this is preventing the subscription from being triggered? If so, why would this be the case?

Comment: What is the value of `this.originalObj` right before you attempt the request?

Comment: @Chris Hamilton. It's just a valid object which contains all the correct object properties. It's not null or undefined

Comment: So you're able to log the object right before you send it, and you're saying HttpClient is not making the request? Are you sure you have the network tab open before the request is supposed to be sent? It won't record requests while it's closed. Also, if the object has a circular reference in it, I think the parser might hang forever.

Comment: Yeah that's right. I stuck a console.log in the http service method `updateObj` and the object is correctly being logged right before the http call. I've made sure the network tab is open before the request is sent and it's definitely not sending the request

Comment: Could you show us what the object looks like, or possibly reproduce it in a stackblitz? Are there any properties that could trap the JSON parse in an infinite loop? The HttpClient performs a JSON parse. A simple test is to change `this.originalObj = updatedObj;` to `this.originalObj = {test: updatedObj.someProperty};` to see if it's the parsing that's getting hung up.

Comment: Could be your object is just enormous and taking forever to parse as well. Reading your previous comments makes me think you have a circular reference in the object, you need to remove that before giving it to HttpClient if you want any chance of turning the object into a string.

Comment: @BailP I wasn't alluding to anything. I simply couldn't infer anything meaningful that might be related to the problem from the question as it was stated so I hoped for clarification. Nothing in your sample code would inherently cause any circular dependencies so it must be something to do with the object that is being passed

Comment: Thanks @ChrisHamilton. The object isn't that large so I don't think that's the issue. Given that there's no errors being logged, I think your suggestion that the parsing is being hung up makes sense and I will explore this